# How to solve $y' = \frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve $y' = \frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}$

Well, I've concluded it is homogenous differential equation, and then I tried:

$y = vx$, $dy = x\cdot dv + v \cdot dx$ and I wasn't able to put integral on both sides because I got to this: $(x^3 + v^2x^3)dv = (2x^2v-v)dx$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:
$$\mbox{d}y = \frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2} \mbox{d}x$$
and with $y=vx$, this becomes:
$$x\mbox{d}v+v\mbox{d}x = \frac{2vx^2}{x^2+v^2x^2} \mbox{d}x$$
Simplifying and rearranging:
$$x\mbox{d}v = \left( \frac{2v}{1+v^2} -v\right) \mbox{d}x$$
And this is almost separated.

Answer (score 3):

$$
(x^2+y^2)y'=2xy\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad y'=\frac{2xy-x^2y'}{y^2}=\left(\frac{x^2}{y}\right)'.$$

Answer (score 2):

$${dy\over dx}={2xy\over x^2+y^2}\\\implies {dy+dx\over dx-dy}={(x+y)^2\over (x-y)^2}\\\implies {d(y+x)\over (y+x)^2}={d(x-y)\over (x-y)^2}$$

There you go!